# Does a Brownian motion depend on a filtration or not?

Tags: brownian-motion

I found many different definitions of Brownian motion. One is

> Def 1: $(B_t)$ is a Brownian motion if it's a.s. continuous, $B_0=0$ a.s., has independents increments and $B_t\sim N(0,t)$.

An other one is

> Def 2: $(B_t)$ is a Brownian motion if it's a.s. continuous,$B_0=0$ a.s., $B_t-B_s$ is independent of $(B_u)_{0\leq u\leq s }$ and $B_t\sim N(0,t)$.

I just saw now in a book that

> Def 3: $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,(\mathcal F_t),(B_t))$ is a Brownian motion if it's a.s. continuous, $B_0=0$ a.s., $B_t-B_s$ is independent of $\mathcal F_s$ and $B_t\sim N(0,t)$.

So it looks that the last definition is a bit more general and for instance, in the last definition, there is a dependance with a filtration.

**Question :** Why do we rather consider definition 1 and 2 and not really definition 3 ? Could someone also explain in what definition 3 would be more helpful ?

Comment: This is true if $$\mathcal{F}_s = \sigma(B_u, 0 \le u \le s)$$
And there are filtrations where both definitions differ (as long as it's really written without any further restrictions on the filtration).

Comment: It depends in which book you read the stuff and what is taught in the book ... The last definition is cleaner compared to your other definition.

Answer (score 2):

Definition 3 provides a little more flexibility. For example, if $B_t=(B^{(1)}_t,B^{(2)}_t)$ is a 2-dimensional Brownian motion (2-dim. version of your Def. 1 or 2) and if $\mathcal F_t:=\sigma(B_s: 0\le s\le t)$, then $B^{(1)}$ is a Brownian motion with respect to $(\mathcal F_t)$ in the sense of your Def. 3, but $\sigma(B^{(1)}_t, 0\le s\le t)$ is strictly continaed in $\mathcal F_t$.